# Flask template rendering 500 error on zeit

Tags: python, flask

Hi I am trying to create my site using Python and Flask, but it returns 500 error.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='files')

@app.route('/projects')
def projects():
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

Folder structure:

```
appdir
 -myapp.py
 +files
  -index.html
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
ENV GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS="--bind=0.0.0.0"
CMD ["gunicorn", "myapp:app"]
```

Exception:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 86, in _get_source_fast
10/22 01:38 PM (2m)
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
10/22 01:38 PM (2m)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html
```

Comment: Any logs? Error message in the response?

Comment: [2018-10-22 10:14:00,800] ERROR in app: Exception on /projects [GET]
10/22 01:14 PM (15m)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 86, in _get_source_fast
10/22 01:14 PM (15m)
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
10/22 01:14 PM (15m)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound:index.html

Comment: @rumo Please add that information to the question

Comment: @rumo Also please include information about the command you are using to start the application

Comment: FROM python:3-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
ENV GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS="--bind=0.0.0.0"
CMD ["gunicorn", "myapp:app"]

Comment: yes please check

Comment: I have just copied your code, working fine: https://imgur.com/REKDRER . Are you sure `index.html` is copying to docker image and not ignored by `.dockerignore` or something else?

Comment: @soon very interesting

Answer (score 0):

try running with some other port number such as 8080

if **name** == '**main**':
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080,debug = True)

Comment: not working still